# use 2 foreach loop in php simultaneously to retrieve the filenames from a directory

Tags: php, html, foreach

I am working on a php code as shown below in which I am trying to retrieve **mp4 and xml files name**.

```
$src_dir    = 'incoming_folder';  /* Place where mp4 file is present */
$mp4_files = preg_grep('~\.(mp4)$~', scandir($src_dir)); /* Line #Y */
print_r($mp4_files);     /* Line #A */ 
$xml_files = preg_grep('~\.(xml)$~', scandir($src_dir)); /* Line #Z */
print_r($xml_files); /* Line #B */
```

**Line#A prints the following:**

```
Array ( [2] => 45017P.mp4 [3] => 45031P.mp4 [5] => hello.mp4
```

**Line#B prints the following:**

```
Array ( [2] => 45017.xml [5] => 45031P.xml [7] => hello.xml )
```

I have integrated **Line#Y** and **Line#Z** code in the html below in order to retrieve the file names from a directory.

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
      <!-- This inline css will go inside addiional css -->
   </tr>
   <th style="width:8%;">House#</th>
   <th style="width:8%;">Date</th>
   <th style="width:8%;" >Time</th>
   <th style="width:8%;">MP4</th>
   <th style="width:8%;" >XML</th>
   <?php    foreach ($mp4_files as $file ) {
      foreach ($xml_files as $file2 ) {     
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file, ".mp4"); ?></td>
      <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo date("F d Y",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file")); ?></td>
      <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo date("H:i:s",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file")); ?></td>
      <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file); ?></td>
      <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"> <?php echo basename($file2); ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }
      }
      ?>
</table>
```

The above **html/php** code prints the following:

```
House#      Date          Time         MP4         XML
45017P  April 30 2019   10:21:12    45017P.mp4  45017P.xml
45017P  April 30 2019   10:21:12    45017P.mp4  45031P.xml
45017P  April 30 2019   10:21:12    45017P.mp4  hello.xml
45031P  May 01 2019     14:56:56    45031P.mp4  45017P.xml
45031P  May 01 2019     14:56:56    45031P.mp4  45031P.xml
45031P  May 01 2019     14:56:56    45031P.mp4  hello.xml
hello   April 30 2019   10:21:12    hello.mp4   45017P.xml
hello   April 30 2019   10:21:12    hello.mp4   45031P.xml
hello   April 30 2019   10:21:12    hello.mp4   hello.xml
```

**Problem Statement:**

In the o/p above for the column House#, I can see two `45017P`, two `45031P`, and two `hello`. I am wondering how I can avoid the redundancy so that it shows something like this:

```
House#    Date           Time           MP4       XML
45017P  April 30 2019   10:21:12    45017P.mp4  45017P.xml 
45031P  May 01 2019     14:56:56    45031P.mp4  45031P.xml
hello   April 30 2019   10:21:12    hello.mp4   hello.xml
```

Comment: inside loop should be receiving the field from the result of outside loop other wise what is the point?In your case what is the relationship between two arrays other than they have similar values

Comment: @zod Yes inside loop should be receiving the field from the result of outside loop. I am not sure how can we do it ?. Can you give me some pointers ?

Comment: $files = [];
foreach ($mp4_files as $file ) {
 $basename = basename($file, ".mp4");
 $files[$basename]['basename'] = $basename
 $files[$basename]['date'] = $date("F d Y",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file"))
 $files[$basename]['time'] = $date("H:i:s",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file"))
 $files[$basename]['mp4'] = basename($file)
}

Comment: foreach ($xml_files as $file ) {
 $basename = basename($file, ".xml");
 if(!array_key_exists($basename, $files) {
  $files[$basename]['basename'] = $basename
  $files[$basename]['date'] = $date("F d Y",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file"))
  $files[$basename]['time'] = $date("H:i:s",filemtime("incoming_folder/$file"))
 }
 $files[$basename]['xml'] = basename($file)
}

Comment: foreach($files as $file) {
 ?>
 <tr>
  <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $file['basename']; ?></td>
  <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $file['date']; ?></td>
  <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $file['time']; ?></td>
  <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $file['mp4']; ?></td>
  <td style="width:8%; text-align:center;"><?php echo $file['xml']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
}

Comment: Sorry for that code, but I can’t do better in a comment... Your problem happen because you run all of your elements from `$xml_files` for each element of your `$mp4_files`

Comment: @Astrea You have pasted three codes. I am wondering which one I should be using ?

Comment: All of them, in the same order. I'm not able to past the full code in only one comment.
And also, remove `$` from `$date(...)`

Comment: and add `;` in each lines when is missing (first and second foreach)

Comment: @Astrea Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nmtdv2yq/1/  I pasted your code inside fiddle.

Comment: @flash Yes, nice! http://jsfiddle.net/20yogvub/2/

Comment: @Astrea Its not working. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Hum, I found some bugs on my code. maybe I can try if you fill the arrays (`$mp4_files` and `$xml_files`) http://jsfiddle.net/20yogvub/4/

Comment: @flash I have make tests and optimizations. You can also do this http://jsfiddle.net/20yogvub/5/